# Writing to a file in child class (in implicit copy constructor for X first required here)

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to create a file in the derived class but I get the error message below.

My code:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal();
    ~Animal();

protected:
    std::string name;
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    Cat(std::string const &filename);

private:
    std::ofstream _file;
};

Cat::Cat(std::string const &filename) : _file(filename.c_str(), std::ios::out)
{
    this->_file.open(filename);
}

int main()
{
    Cat c1 = Cat("cat.txt");
}
```

and I am getting the following error,

```
    In file included from animal.cpp:3:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/fstream:169:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:139:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/streambuf:486:64: error: base class 'std::__1::ios_base' has
      private copy constructor
_LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE(class _LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE_TYPE_VIS basic_ios<char>)
                                                               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:133:32: note: in implicit copy constructor for
      'std::__1::basic_ios<char>' first required here
    class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS basic_ofstream;
                               ^
animal.cpp:15:7: note: in implicit copy constructor for 'std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' first required here
class Cat : public Animal
      ^
animal.cpp:34:14: note: in implicit copy constructor for 'Cat' first required here
    Cat c1 = Cat("cat.txt");
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:313:5: note: declared private here
    ios_base(const ios_base&); // = delete;
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Streams cannot be copied. `Cat` contains a stream, therefore `Cat` cannot be copied.  `Cat c1 = Cat("cat.txt");` doesn't really copy a `Cat`, but it required `Cat` be copy-able. Replacement: `Cat c1("cat.txt");`

Comment: cannot reproduce with the code you posted. After fixing missing definitions of `Animal` it [compiles and runs fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7JMd4dHacbzIfTjE), anyhow the problem is that you cannot copy the stream

Comment: This should not be an error since C++11, because `Cat c1 = Cat("cat.txt");` can use the move constructor in C++11 and later. Are you purposefully using old C++03 or even C++98? (If so, you should probably tag that. If not you configured your compiler wrong.)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I copy pasted your code, it does not work, gives the same error.

Comment: @uneven_mark (c++/4.2.1, clang-902.0.39.2) I am using a mac, with g++. Is this old? OK now I compiled with cpp11 flag, and it worked. Thanks, also user458's suggestion worked with the older version.

Comment: @EmmetB No, I don't think so. (I guess clang-902.0.39.2 is Clang 9) You probably gave your compiler a flag similar to `-std=c++98` or something like that, either manually or through an IDE/build setting.

Comment: Not too old, but you may have to add an extra compiler option to get the compiler to build the program according to the newer rules in more recent standards. I don't know XCode worth beans, but there should be a configuration option that allows you to set the C++ Standard revision or dialect.

Comment: @uneven_mark I was just doing g++ animal.cpp from the terminal, it was giving error. Now giving -std=c++11 flag solved all the problem, but do you think writing Cat c1= Cat("cat.txt") is a bad practice

Comment: @EmmetB If at all it is only a bad practice because your are repeating `Cat` twice. Since C++17 (which you should probably use instead of `-std=c++11`) these are even guaranteed to do the same thing. Another alternative is `auto c1 = Cat("cat.txt");` if you prefer that. (Spells the type only once, `auto` is deduced by the compiler.) Which you choose is mostly a matter of style.

Comment: See if you can use `-std=c++17`. Might as well compile to the most recent Standard and get all the wording-fixes and features